Fastest RPC node for solana transaction paod
Hello guys what is the fastest RPC node for solana transaction im looking for a paid option

This is such a subjective question because factors such as latency come into play.
Triton and Helius have great reputation, but I'd say play with each one to get the one which works best for you from this list, https://solana.com/rpc
